# System.EntryPointNotFoundException: SetConsoleTitle assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null) on Replit.com

Tags: c#, .net, dll, replit, entrypointnotfoundexcept

Trying to run a small C# project with uploaded DLLs on Replit.com

Uploaded my DLL (Unit4.dll).
In Visual Studio on my desktop it works after I Added References to three Windows DLLs:
System.Drawing.Common.dll, System.Windows.Forms.dll, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.dll.
Downloaded the three DLLs and Uploaded them to Files on Replit.com
Changed the .replit command to
run = "set -e; mcs Main.cs -r:Unit4.dll -r:System.Windows.Forms.dll -r:System.Drawing.Common.dll -r:System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.dll; mono Main.exe"

It compiles and runs, but gets a the Runtime Exception I added below.
Not sure what is missing or what is wrong and how to fix it.
Please help.

Unhandled Exception:
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: SetConsoleTitle assembly: type: member:(null)
at (wrapper managed-to-native) Unit4.BinTreeCanvasLib.Window.SetConsoleTitle(string)
at Unit4.BinTreeCanvasLib.Window.get_Instance () [0x00067] in <6a068eaab6084265b4099e03c146f5d7>:0
at Unit4.BinTreeCanvasLib.TreeCanvas.InitTreeToDraw[T] (Unit4.CollectionsLib.BinNode`1[T] tree) [0x00366] in <6a068eaab6084265b4099e03c146f5d7>:0  at Unit4.BinTreeCanvasLib.TreeCanvas.AddTree[T] (Unit4.CollectionsLib.BinNode`1[T] tree) [0x00001] in <6a068eaab6084265b4099e03c146f5d7>:0
at Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00054] in <95445213fc8b4cc9ba753b3d428925d5>:0